# common support for MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Why common support is important for MLE? What happen if a family of distributions 
fail to have common support? I would like to understand where and why in the proof of MLE properties (existense, consistency, effciency, asymptotic normality) we need the regularity condition of common support.

Comment: Please cite a reference where "common support" is stated as a regularity condition for MLE

Answer (score 1):

Deriving the key properties of MLE (e.g. Cramer-Rao, asymptotic efficiency relative to M-estimators, etc) depends on being able to differentiate under the integral sign.

The validity of differentiating under expectation is usually established via dominated convergence theorem. When the distributions do not have common support, the dominated convergence argument may not apply and MLE results can break down.

Consider, for example, the property

$$
E_{\theta}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(x;\theta)] = 0,
$$

which is needed for Cramer-Rao. This is obtained by differentiating $E_{\theta}[f(x;\theta)]$ under the expectation sign. (It also makes MLE a method of moment type estimator.)

Here is a counterexample where the distributions do not have common support.

Consider the family of uniform distributions parametrized by $\theta$: 
$f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}1_{[0,\theta]}$.
$$
E_{\theta}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(x;\theta)] = -\frac{1}{\theta} \neq 0,
$$

Cramer-Rao lower bound does not hold in this case. The dominated convergence type argument breaks down because $-\frac{1}{\theta}$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yet, the fact that the MLE estimatior exists and is maximal at the true value depends only Jensen inequaility (or not?), so as long as there are obseravations for which the PDF is not zero, this estimator exists and I believe it is also conssitent. Am I right? Despite the fact that Rao Cramer and efficiency may not hold.

Comment: How do you argue for consistency here? Consistency is based on, the population function $E_{\theta_0}[\log f(x;\theta)]$ have the true parameter $\theta_0$ as maximizer and WULLN. Here this function is not even defined.

Comment: I do not understand. It can be defined for certain theta. For example, the MLE for the uniform distribution in the example above is max(xi) provided [x1....xn] are iid. For large n, I think this is a consistent estimator. Indeed, the likelihood is zero for theta<max(xi) hence log[likeliood] is not defined for these values. Yet, the MLE estimator exists. Am I right?

Comment: Does common support, maybe combined with other conditions, are sufficient to gurantee existance/consistency but they are not nessasery?

Comment: Why do you say MLE is the sample max? The maximizer is not unique.

Comment: If you plot the likelihood you get a function which is zero before max(xi), and from then it decreases monotonically. The function is not continues at max(xi) which is its MLE. Due to this discontinueity, the MLE cannot be found by diffrentiation. Yet, it exists.